# Heroku Server not working with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app that uses Devise for user auth. In localhost:3000 my site works perfectly. I can signup, login, etc. However, when I `git push heroku` and try going to sign up or login, I just get a 500 error.

Some specs of my site: I'm using sqlite (I heard that may be a problem) and have changed the **/users/sign_up** route to **/sign** and **/users/sign_in** route to **/login**. My **/configure/environments/development.rb** has the code `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` and **/configure/environments/production.rb** has the code `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myPersonalApp.heroku.com' }`

What is wrong that is causing the 500 error only on heroku?

Comment: You'll be using PostgreSQL on Heroku, you should switch your development environment to PostgreSQL as well. And what's in your error log?

Comment: i used sqllite on my pc and of course postgres on heroku works fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just a thought - Do you have any outstanding migrations that you have not performed on Heroku? That's something I always forget - Just run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and see if that helps. Might not be an error in your code after all.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `heroku rake` has been depreceted, now it would be `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Had exactly same issue with Rails 4 and heroku. This answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

have you enabled SendGrid on your account so that it can actually send the messages?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a different reason:
Don't forget to set

```
config.mailer_sender = 'your-email-address.xyz'
```

in devise.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Running heroku run rake db:migrate worked for me

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the already-accepted answer, so is only a distraction for site users.  Suggest you remove it.